# How can I move a group of picture in one directory to another?

Tags: picture-library, directory

How can I move a group of picture in directory A to directory B for a picture library in SharePoint 2007?

Comment: I need to move or copy more pictures from one Picture Library to another picture library after certain months, using SharePoint Designer 2010 and without coding. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three different ways:

1) open each location with Windows Explorer view and drag-n-drop from one location to the other

2) open each location in SharePoint Designe and drop-n-drag from one location to the other

3) connect with a WebDAV tool like BitKinex to each location and copy from one location to the other

Comment: Got your point, but is there ways to do it on SharePoint Site itself (without using Windows Explorer, SharePoint Designer or WebDAV tool) as not all of our user are experienced computer user?

Comment: For my end users, the windows explorer method works best as many people understand the concept of a shard drive. I just provide them with the simple instructions.

Comment: @john there is an option in the actions menu of the document library called "open in windows explorer" that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use the Copy and Move actions available on the [Manage Content and Structure](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx) page. However, this page is only available with MOSS 2007 - pure WSS 3.0 deployments do not have it.

Second, there is the option to employ a third-party tool like [CopyMove for SharePoint 2007](http://www.sharepointproducts.com). It was designed for end-users but comes with a price tag.

Comment: Very strange. I try using the Copy and Move actions available on the manage Content and Structure page, it seems that if a Picture Library contain X number of folder (where X is a number), pictures located at the root of the Picture Library cannot be copy to the sub-folder as only the library is shown?

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at using a Send-To location if this is going to be repeated often. This way, you can go to the items, and using the drop-down send them to the new location.

Comment: I wish to let my end-user to be able to create their own folder (and move files to another folder if necessary). I can still use your idea to define special folder that all user can send-to it.